# Reference cell not calculating

Tags: vba, excel

I am having an issue with a cell that has a formula in it, but it's not calculating. I am using Excel 2013 and the data is as follows:
I have 12 cells(z14:ab17) the user will place a numeric value in. The formulated cell has a formula that uses the numeric cells to calculate a value, but all the cell displays is #VALUE!. The formula is

```
=IF((ISNUMBER(SUM(Z14:AB17))),PI()/4/32^2*(Z14^2+AA14^2+AB14^2+Z15^2+AA15^2+AB15^2+Z16^2+AA16^2+AB16^2+Z17^2+AA17^2+AB17^2),0).
```

In the VBA side, I have

```
Global Const PI = 3.1415927
```

All the user input cells are formatted for numeric values, and the formulated cell is also formulated to calculate and display a numeric value. Can anyone help with why the cells is not calculating? This did work at one time, but now it doesn't and I have no idea what could have happened. Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't actually have a period at the end of your formula do you?  The formula (sans period) works just fine and calculates for me successfully.  Is your workbook set to Automatic calculation?

Comment: Also, the VBA line is wholly unnecessary and not actually used or referenced by the formula.

Comment: File > Options > Formulas > Workbook Calculation = Automatic. You can also check this when you are expecting cells to calculate and they aren't.

Comment: No, I don't have a period at the end of the formula lol. Sorry for that. Also, the workbook calculation is already set to Automatic. In VB, would PI automatically reference the Global Const, although it's being used in the formula? And if it's working on your end, I have no clue why it isn't on mine...

Comment: And it says "A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type". Isn't this referring to the formatting of the cells? All cells are formatted as numeric values. I am lost...

Comment: if you copy it to a new sheet or workbook, still same issue?

Comment: Yes. Same issue. Is there a way to make sure that Events are enabled?

Comment: I figured it out. The "empty" cells have to have a 0 for numeric value, vs can be blank if formatted as General. Thanks for all the help!